# Print particular values from object based on comparison

Tags: ruby

I am working on developing a UI wherein I need to retrieve particular values from an object based on conditions. object looks like below.

```
Category = {["personal_care_appliances", "glwise_category_config", "{catWhitelist: []}"],
            ["wine","glwise_category_config","{}"],
            ["shoes","glwise_category_config","{catWhitelist: []}"],
            ["automotive","glwise_category_config",],
            ["watch","glwise_category_config","{catWhitelist: []}"]
]
```

I need to print first element such as personal_care_appliances,shoes,watch as they have a component catWhitelist: [].

I tried using map and array syntax but it did not work.

PS. I am quite new to Ruby and learning through online docs.

Comment: What is not work? Show your attempts please.

Comment: "it did not work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I tried below few methods..  1) category.each do |var|  puts var.values [3] end 2) category.each do |var|  puts var.map {|x| x.values[3]}

Comment: comparison is yet to be done which i am sure I can handle. But firstly tried extracting subelements

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that category is an array of arrays (which is not quite clear from your question), try map first element of nested array if the nested array includes `"{catWhitelist: []}"`:

```
category.map { |e| e[0] if e.include? "{catWhitelist: []}" }.compact

# => ["personal_care_appliances", "shoes", "watch"]
```

Or, better to select required subarrays before to map it:

```
category.select { |e| e.include? "{catWhitelist: []}" }.map{ |e| e[0] }
```

Answer (score 0):

If we assume you have this array:

```
category = [
  ["personal_care_appliances", "glwise_category_config", "{catWhitelist: []}"],
  ["wine","glwise_category_config","{}"],
  ["shoes","glwise_category_config","{catWhitelist: []}"],
  ["automotive","glwise_category_config",],
  ["watch","glwise_category_config","{catWhitelist: []}"]
]
```

and you want to get only the items which have catWhitelist, then you can use a method like:

```
def with_cat_whitelist(category)
  result = []
  category.each do |item|
    result << item.first if item.last == "{catWhitelist: []}"
  end
  result
end
```